# How do I reset the widgets like combobox and entry fields after submission in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-entry

When I start my application, all my fields (disabled and normal status) and combo boxes are blank, as they should be. I have 3 frames with combo boxes and text fields (some of them are disabled). The problem happens when I make a submission, but the values stay in the widgets. Is there a short cut to get the widgets to reset to blank after a submission is made?

I have tried destroy(), but that I need to re-use widgets so I can't use it.

```
def submission():
    print(txt_Entry.get())
    print(combobox.get())
```

There is no error message, I just need the frame to appear as it was when I start the application.

Comment: `text_entry.delete(0, 'end')`. If you are using a `StringVar()` for your combobox you can do `string_var_name.set('Default value you want')`.

Comment: please could you build a sample so we can help you for what you need exactly ?

Comment: string_var_name.set('Default value you want'), exactly what I wanted, thanks!